# Getting 400: Bitbucket API command to grant Access on Branch

Tags: rest, api, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to automate the process to provide the user access on Bitbucket branches on the cloud via bitbucket API using curl command. Please help me with the command as I have visit [link](https://docs.atlassian.com/DAC/rest/stash/3.0.1/stash-branch-permissions-rest.html#paging-params). But no luck.

I have run the below command but getting 400. Please help where I am doing the wrong.

> .\curl -i -u user:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"type": "no-delet
>   es","matcher": {"id": "refs/heads/branchname","displayId": "branchname","type": {"id": "BRANCH","name": "Bra
>   nch"},"active": true},"users": ["user"],"groups": []}' 'https://api.bitbucket.org/rest/branch-permissions/2.0/pro
>   jects/projectkey/repos/reponame/restrictions'

Comment: You're looking at Bitbucket Server documentation but sending requests to Bitbucket Cloud.

Comment: Can you help me where I am wrong in command?

Comment: The Bitbucket Cloud API is documented at api.bitbucket.org . It looks like you're trying to do something like https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/branch-restrictions

Comment: Right, @JimRedmond. But getting the error while doing the same.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the new path, then?